# How to iterate through a list of strings returned from a web service using JQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services

This is my first JQuery experience and I'm on quite a tight deadline.  It's a bit of an embarrassing question, but here goes.  I'm calling a web service  that returns a list of strings (which works and returns OK).  Code is below

```
$(document).ready(
    function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "CatList.asmx/GetCatergoies",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: onActionCompleted
        });
    }
)

function onActionCompleted(data) {

    var resultData = data['d'];
    alert(resultData);
 }
```

The alert produces a comma seperate string of the results from the web service.  I can't figure out for the life of me how I can iterate through the results.  When I do something like this:

```
resultData.each(
   alert(this)
)
```

All I get in Firebug is this error:

```
resultData.each is not a function
```

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks! I wouldn't have been able to solve it without the feedback.  I'm still not completely sure what format resultData is.  I did some copy and paste on the code so not sure what data['d'] converts the list into in json terms.

When I tried the split on resultdata I got this error in Firebug:

resultData.split is not a function

In the end I just used the $.each() on resultdata without the split and it worked.

```
function onActionCompleted(data) {

    var resultData = data['d'];
    $.each(resultData, function() {
        alert(this)
    })
}
```

Comment: This means that data['d'] is already an array :). How did you came up with the idea that it's a comma delimited string ?

Comment: because alert(resultData); displayed a command delimited string.  That must be how javascrip formats arrays?

Answer (score 8):

Using **[Array.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)** will produce an array:

```
var string = "red,blue,green,orange"

$.each(string.split(','), function(){
  alert(this)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider [`string.split()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#split) instead of jQuery:

```
var items = results.split(',');

for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
  alert( items[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like your webservice gave you a csv-string. Split it into an array, wrap jQuery around it and add a callback function for each of the elements like this:

```
$(resultData.split(",")).each(function () {
    alert(this);
});
```

Comment: each does also work on normal arrays. So $.each(resultData.split(","), function(){}); should work also.

Comment: Indeed, I just prefer the $(array).each(callback) syntax over $.each(array, callback) for readability purposes.