# How to populate drop down values using servlet response

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I am able to have the response from a servlet and also able to show it on jsp page, but if I try to populate the same in a drop down, i am not able to-

**Servlet code**

```
String sql = "SELECT records from department";
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
Map<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

while (rs.next()) {
  options.put(rs.getString("records"),rs.getString("records"));
}
String json = new Gson().toJson(options);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

**JSP code**---

*JS code*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {                           // When the HTML DOM is ready loading, then execute the following function...
    $('.btn-click').click(function () {                  // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somebutton" and assign the following function to its "click" event...
        $.get('/testservlet', function (responseJson) {    // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response JSON...
            //alert(responseJson);
            var $select = $('#maindiv');                           // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "someselect".
            $select.find('option').remove();                          // Find all child elements with tag name "option" and remove them (just to prevent duplicate options when button is pressed again).
            $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {               // Iterate over the JSON object.
                $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select); // Create HTML <option> element, set its value with currently iterated key and its text content with currently iterated item and finally append it to the <select>.
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML Code**--

```
<input type="button" class="btn-click" id="best" value="check"/>
<div id="maindiv" style="display: block"></div>
```

If I create a `<ul>` and `<li>` I can have the data from the response on my page but not able to create the select options? Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it again after removing beginning `/`.

```
$.get('testservlet', function (responseJson)
```

The JSON string is not in proper way. It should be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233354/how-to-iterate-json-data-in-jquery). Why are you using JSON string here whereas you are passing only records as key as well as value.

Simply return a comma separated string from Servlet and split it jQuery.

Find example here for [Iterating a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920362/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-strings-returned-from-a-web-service-using-jquer)

Sample code:

```
var items = responseJson.split(',');

for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('<option>').val(items[i]).text(items[i]).appendTo($select); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Braj. But I am following BalusC suggestion from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/2480307). It should work in the map case as well, in the way I am doing?

Comment: You have to modify your JSON string. I have shared you some links. Have you looked any one.

Comment: Yes,that's another way of doing following to do that way :) Thanks for sharing

Comment: If you think to make my post more helpful for others then you are free to modify my post.

Comment: Sure Will update :) also I have figured out why my earlier code was not working. It was a silly html error, I had to add `<select>`tag to make the append work. But thanks got the other way out to do this.